# Java How do use nested properties in spring application

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a spring application properties, how can i use nested properties

e.g.

```
r.password=${password}
r.user=${username}
r.host=${rabbit_url}

rabbitmq.config={"host":"${r.host}","username":"${r.user}","password":"${r.password}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Value` annotation to inject these nested properties from your properties file. Placeholders in your property will be resolved if they've been defined previously.
e.g -

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppProperties {
    
    private final String foo;
    
    public AppProperties(@Value("${rabbitmq.config}") String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```